# Find repeated elements in a having count

Tags: sql

I have a having count, where I detect elements that repeat more than once.

```
select MstDocCabId, count (*) as 'Repetition Number'
from skmov (nolock)
group by MstDocCabId
having count(MstDocCabId) > 1
```

So, the result is similar to:

```
+-------------+-------------------+
| MstDocCabId | Repetition Number |
+-------------+-------------------+
| 16513519    | 4                 |
+-------------+-------------------+
```

So, if i make `select * from skmov where MstDocCabId=16513519` i can see 4 elements that have the same mstdoccabid, example

```
+----------+----------+
|  MstID   |   Col2   |
+----------+----------+
| 38600690 | 16513519 |
| 38600691 | 16513519 |
| 38600692 | 16513519 |
| 38600693 | 16513519 |
+----------+----------+
```

For each row that repeats the *mstdoccabid*, there is a column called *product*, which may or should have different value for each case:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| MstID     | mstdoccabid | Product |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| 38600690  | 16513519    | AAAA    |
| 38600691  | 16513519    | BBBB    |
| 38600692  | 16513519    | CCCC    |
| 38600693  | 16513519    | DDDD    |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
```

My question is how I could detect cases where the *mstdoccabid* is repeated, and where the *product* is the same (example Product AAAA).

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| MstID     | mstdoccabid | Product |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| 38600690  | 16513519    | AAAA    |
| 38600691  | 16513519    | BBBB    |
| 38600692  | 16513519    | CCCC    |
| 38600693  | 16513519    | AAAA    |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: Is there some reason why it's not simply adding `Product` to the GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by `Product` as well and it will work:

```
select MstDocCabId, count (*) as 'Repetition Number'
from skmov (nolock)
group by MstDocCabId, Product
having count(MstDocCabId) > 1
```